# Get .classpath from random location

Tags: java, reference, classpath, static-methods

I am trying to get my `.classpath` file as an [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) or [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). If I have a class in the default package, I can simply use [`getResourceAsStream(".classpath")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)):

```
ArrayList<String> attributes = new ArrayList<String>();
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
// Access classpath from class in default package
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(Main.class.getResourceAsStream(".classpath"));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("classpathentry");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

    System.out.println(nNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("path").getNodeValue());
}
```

But in situations where I do not know its location relative to the class accessing it, I cannot use this method. I attempted using the environment variable `CLASSPATH`, but that gave me the path to a nonexistent file (`C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip`). I also tried  `System.getProperty("java.class.path");`, but that only gave me the name of the current jar. I am not trying to get the current jar or its path, but rather the `.classpath` XML formatted file that is found in (every?) IDE projects and jar files.
[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Is there a clean (static) way to access the class path without entering its location, possibly through static references? I feel that there might be way which uses [`ClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html), but I can not find any such methods.

Comment: Are you looking for `getResourceAsStream("/.classpath")`? What does 'autonomously' mean in your title? There are no `.classpath` files in any of ,y projects or JAR files. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to access the xml file that is found in every jar, not the literal path.

I think you are looking for something that does not exist.  (Sure, it exists in the source project.  But not (normally) in the binary JAR file.  Take a look inside the JAR file!!)

The JAR file spec makes no mention of a ".classpath" file.  Non-executable JAR files don't need a classpath, and executable JAR files express the classpath via a manifest attribute.  (Reference [JAR File Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jar/jar.html)).

Now it is *technically possible* to copy the ".classpath" file from your IDE project into the JAR file (e.g. by customizing the Maven POM file, if you use Maven), but I've never heard of an IDE that puts the file into a JAR by default.

But ... if there are ".classpath" files in your JAR files (somehow), you should be able to find them at runtime.  One possibility is to use:

- https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner

One of the advertised features of that library is searching for files in the resource tree that match a name regex.

Comment: Yea ... that took a bit of finding.

Answer (score 0):

From [How To Get Classpath in Java](https://javabeat.net/get-classpath-java/):

`public class JavaCoreExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Call System property to get the classpath value
        String classpathStr = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        System.out.print(classpathStr);
    }
}`

If you run the program using `sbt run` or another launcher like Maven you will only see `sbt-launch.jar` or the launcher jar shown. This is because that is the in fact the classpath for SBT or Maven, not for your client program.

If you run the program from an IDE (like IntelliJ) you will see the entire classpath:

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/mnt/_/work/experiments/scala/stackOverflow/target/scala-2.12/classes:/home/mslinn/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.4.jar:/opt/idea-IU-173.3727.127/lib/idea_rt.jar:/opt/idea-IU-173.3727.127/lib/rt/debugger-agent.jar`

Same thing will happen if you run the program by launching it with the class path specified.

Comment: I answered the question that you originally asked. I see you just changed the question. Please accept this answer and ask another.